# Switch focus to reopened tab in Chrome - selenium

Tags: selenium

I am trying to achieve the below flow in selenium ,

1. click on a link to open new tab(child1) from parent window
2. close the driver (child1) after performing certain actions
3. Open the same link(child1) again to perform another set of actions

I am able to achieve the first two steps successfully by switching focus. But I am stuck at the third step where I am not able to focus on the same reopened tab. I get the below error,
org.openqa.selenium.StaleElementReferenceException: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document

```
public class abc {

String currentWindow = driver.getWindowHandle();

public void action1() {

//Click on main menu that open a new tab 
for (String handle : driver.getWindowHandles()) {
        if (!handle.equals(currentWindow)) {
            driver.switchTo().window(handle);
        }

//Perform the actions 
driver.close();
driver.switchTo().window(currentWindow);

}

public void action2(){

//Click on main menu which reopen the same tab
for (String handle : driver.getWindowHandles()) {
                if (!handle.equalsIgnoreCase(currentWindow)) {
                    System.out.println("Port Response : switch focus");
                    driver.switchTo().window(handle);
                    break;
                }
            }
//perform a set of actions 
driver.close();
driver.switchTo().window(currentWindow);
}

}//end of abc
```

I want to create the actions more like a reusable independent action so I would like to close all tabs and reopen them again for other set of action. Please let me know if you need any more details on this.

Comment: you have to run getWindowHandles command again when u get StaleElementException
and then switch to reopen tab...

Comment: @Amit, I get this StaleElementException  after I reopen the tab and tried to do some operation .

Comment: Make sure you use the Explicit wait before interacting with the element on the new tab.

Comment: @supputuri I added enough wait before and after switching focus. Still it doesn't work . In the above code, if I comment out action1 and directly run action2 it works . So there is no issue with the code. Only focus I am not able to switch properly between the tabs.